# dynamically created range form, only the last range works , why?

Tags: javascript, range

I am trying to dynamically generate some range forms lately but I got stuck at these, only the last range does work even if they have different id´s. Why is that ? I assume it doesn´t like my global rangenum variable but why ?

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<script>

var rangenum = 0;
var rangediv = new Array();
var rangeform = new Array();


var range = {};
range['position'] = {
  controls : [{   pos: "parent",
                  inc: 1,
                  out: "oX",
                   id: "x",
                label: 35,
                  vis: "block",
                 step: 0.1,
                  min: -100,
                  max: 100,
                  def: 0 },
              {   pos: "parent",
                  inc: 1,
                  out: "oY",
                   id: "y",
                label: 36,
                  vis: "block",
                 step: 0.1,
                  min: -100,
                  max: 100,
                  def: 0 }
             ]
}

 function rangebox(obj) {

       prnt = document.getElementById(obj.pos);
       rangenum++;


       rangediv[obj.id] = document.createElement("DIV");

       rangediv[obj.id].id='div_'+obj.id;
       rangeform[obj.id] = document.createElement("FORM");

       rangeform[obj.id].oninput= function() {
         input=document.getElementById('i'+rangenum).value;
         document.getElementById('o'+rangenum).value=input;
         console.log(input);
        }

          rangeoutput = document.createElement("OUTPUT");
          rangeoutput.id = 'o'+rangenum;
          rangeoutput.value = obj.def;
          rangeoutput.innerHTML=obj.def;

          rangeinput = document.createElement("INPUT");
          rangeinput.type='range';
          rangeinput.step=obj.step;
          rangeinput.min=obj.min;
          rangeinput.max=obj.max;
          rangeinput.value=obj.def;
          rangeinput.id = 'i'+rangenum;
          rangeinput.innerHTML=obj.def;

       prnt.appendChild(rangediv[obj.id]);



       rangediv[obj.id].appendChild(rangeform[obj.id]);
       rangeform[obj.id].appendChild(rangeoutput);
       rangeform[obj.id].appendChild(rangeinput);
 }

 function getrange () {
 i=0;
   while (range['position'].controls[i]) {
     rangebox(range['position'].controls[i]);
     i++;
   }
 }




</script>

<div id="parent"></div>


<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="getrange()">get range</a>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Array ... object ... array ... What kind of object you actually want `rangediv` and `rangeform` to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code *rangenum* is the problem,
try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
  <script>

var rangenum = 0;
var rangediv = new Array();
var rangeform = new Array();


var range = {};
range['position'] = {
  controls : [{   pos: "parent",
                  inc: 1,
                  out: "oX",
                   id: "x",
                label: 35,
                  vis: "block",
                 step: 0.1,
                  min: -100,
                  max: 100,
                  def: 0 },
              {   pos: "parent",
                  inc: 1,
                  out: "oY",
                   id: "y",
                label: 36,
                  vis: "block",
                 step: 0.1,
                  min: -100,
                  max: 100,
                  def: 0 }
             ]
}

 function rangebox(obj) {

       prnt = document.getElementById(obj.pos);
       rangenum++;


       rangediv[obj.id] = document.createElement("DIV");

       rangediv[obj.id].id='div_'+obj.id;
       rangeform[obj.id] = document.createElement("FORM");

       rangeform[obj.id].oninput= function() {
         console.log(document.activeElement.id.slice(1,2)); 
         var idval=document.activeElement.id.slice(1,2)     
         input=document.getElementById('i'+idval).value;
         document.getElementById('o'+idval).value=input;
        //  console.log(input);
        }

          rangeoutput = document.createElement("OUTPUT");
          rangeoutput.id = 'o'+rangenum;
          rangeoutput.value = obj.def;
          rangeoutput.innerHTML=obj.def;

          rangeinput = document.createElement("INPUT");
          rangeinput.type='range';
          rangeinput.step=obj.step;
          rangeinput.min=obj.min;
          rangeinput.max=obj.max;
          rangeinput.value=obj.def;
          rangeinput.id = 'i'+rangenum;
          rangeinput.innerHTML=obj.def;

       prnt.appendChild(rangediv[obj.id]);



       rangediv[obj.id].appendChild(rangeform[obj.id]);
       rangeform[obj.id].appendChild(rangeoutput);
       rangeform[obj.id].appendChild(rangeinput);
 }

 function getrange () {
 i=0;
   while (range['position'].controls[i]) {
     rangebox(range['position'].controls[i]);
     i++;
   }
 }




</script>

  <div id="parent"></div>

  <a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="getrange()">get range</a>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, that one works. I Already had the feeling that rangenum causes the trouble but I don´t know why. Anyway, thanks... saves me some more hours ;-)

Comment: a minor change to your solution to make it work for more than 9 range inputs: var idval=document.activeElement.id.slice(1,document.activeElement.id.length)